# Problema con ruta en express

Tags: nodejs, express, model-view-controller

Este es mi servidor:

```
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const app = express();

const { mongoose } = require('./database');

// Settings
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
var port = app.get('port');

// Middlewares
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.json());

// Routes
app.use('api/employees', require("./routes/employee.routes"));


//Starting the Server
app.listen(port, ()=> {
  console.log("Server on port: ", port);
});
```

el funciona bien y conecta a la base de datos muy bien. Lo que no funciona es la ruta:

```
app.use('api/employees', require("./routes/employee.routes"));
```

que cada vez que la sigo localhost:3000/api/employees me devuelve el status code 404

Esta es la ruta:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const employee = require('../controllers/employee.controller');

router.get('/', employee.getEmployees);

module.exports = router;
```

y por supuesto acá tengo el controlador:

```
const employeeCtrl = {};

employeeCtrl.getEmployees = (req,res) => {
  res.json({
    status: 'Employees Here'
  })
}

module.exports = employeeCtrl;
```

¿Por qué me sale ese error?

Comment: A ti ruta api/employee te falta el final un /

Comment: es exactamente lo que dice @JackNavaRow en esta  linea te falta un / al principio de la ruta app.use('api/employees', require("./routes/employee.routes"));